# Stack bootstrap glyphicons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the following bootstrap icon

```
class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"
```

and I want to change the color of the button and I use the following 
But now I want that the plus icon will be in circle like this ,how should I do that? [image]

```
    i.glyphicon {
        color: white;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another icon package called [font-awesome](http://fontawesome.io/examples/) has better flexibility and feature of stacking icons together. Bootstrap 3 containing Glyphicons don't have much options so I took out the CSS from font-awesome and adopted it for Glyphicon.

The HTML looks like:

```
<span class="glyphicon-stack">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle glyphicon-stack-2x"></i>
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyphicon-stack glyphicon-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
```

The main CSS:

```
.glyphicon-stack {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
width: 2em;
height: 2em;
line-height: 2em;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.glyphicon-circle{
position: relative;
border-radius: 50%;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
padding-top: 100%;
background: black;
}

.glyphicon-stack-1x {
line-height: inherit;
}

.glyphicon-stack-1x, .glyphicon-stack-2x {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}
```

For the styling of the icons (color, size), you can create more css class properties and add to the respective icons.

Have a look at this **[example.](http://www.bootply.com/Q58fGlTO1R)**

Comment: Thanks but how should I add all the classes as you mentioned since my code is like this  <a href="#" id="Row"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;New</a>

Comment: @shopiaT Try placing the `<span>..</span>` inside the anchor tags.

Comment: Do you mean Like this that?since this is not working          <a href="#" id="addRow">
            <span class="glyphicon-stack">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle glyphicon-stack-2x"></i>
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyphicon-stack glyphicon-stack-1x"></i>
            </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;New
        </a>

Comment: @shopiaT Do you not see any icon inside the circle? Could you please paste the code you've tried (possibly a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com)) and a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: "Bootstrap 2.3 was using font-awesome icons" False. Bootstrap itself has never used Font Awesome.

Comment: @cvrebert You're right xD I was under a grave misunderstanding since I've used lots of bootstrap templates and the 2.3 versions came with font-awesome icons and in my mind I had assumed it to be default. Will change my answer. Thanks for informing!

Answer (score 3):

You can add some simple css rules to that element, like:

```
i {
    background: green;
    padding: 3px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    color: white;
}
```

You could abstract it, creating two classes, like i.circle.green, and split those rules between them, so you don't override default bootstrap classes.

Comment: HI Gregorio +1 ,1. the border radius is depracted ,"this is the erorr which I get ,there is something else which I can use? 2.The is a way to make the plus in bold or change the lines of it to be little bit bigger?

Comment: You only need border-radius: 50%; to get a circle, but anyways fine job i would probably stuff the i element inside a span

Comment: Unfortunately, Glyphicons' weight is not configurable...for the border radius, what does it mean "it's deprecated"? I guess it won't work on ie older versions, but you could use Pie library to polyfill some css3 rules, including border radius.

Comment: my question is that I have the following div and under it I have table and I want the button to be on top of the table with little space beteen them,when I add <br> the space is long and when I remove it its short ,how can I move it little up ? this is the code <div class="text-right" > <a href="#" id="Row"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;New</a> <br/> </div>

Answer (score 1):

as already mentioned, you can do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class='test'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></div>
<span class="glyphicon-class">.glyphicon .glyphicon-plus</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.test{
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    background: green;
    padding: 3px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    color: white;
    text-align:center
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/InferOn/AtmNr/5/

Comment: Thanks Infer-on +1,I've additional question two question 1.how should I make the + in white like with bold,I want it to be more thick ?2.how should I take this button and move it little bit up since currelntly the circle is on top some element...

Comment: you should provide us more of your markup, probably another question will be more appropriate

Comment: my question is that I have the following div and under it I have table and I want the button to be on top of the table with little space beteen them,when I add <br> the space is long and when I remove it its short ,how can I move it little up ? this is the code <div class="text-right" >
            <a href="#" id="Row"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;New</a>
            <br/>
        </div>

Comment: @shopiaT you should seriously edit your question(providing additional markup to figure what you need) or else(better) make a new question (providing all the markup to figure what you need) have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done natively in Bootstrap by:

```
<i class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center position-relative bi bi-circle lh-1" style="font-size: 15rem; color: cornflowerblue;">
   <i style="font-size: 8rem;" class="position-absolute bi bi-card-checklist"></i>
</i>
```

Comment: Good answer - FYI - this is for bootstrap 5

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the icon using .circle class.

Comment: That's such a useful answer really.